# Upload file to MongoDB with mongo-go-driver using GridFS

Tags: mongodb, go, nosql

I looked the official GridFS documentation, and did some google search but there isn't any clear documentation on using GridFS in the official mongo-go-driver.

So the further I could see is uploading the content of the file as below:

```
// Read the File
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("data.txt")
check(err)
.....
// insert the collection to a document
uplodedResult, err := fileCollection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.D{
{"file", data},
})
```

How do I upload the file instead not only its contents.

Comment: What is a file other than its contents? Please clarify.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg the file is of any kind could be a pdf, movie, mp3, ms office, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So as per this documentation https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/gridfs, we need to first create a new bucket with `NewBucket()`, than use `OpenUploadStream()` to initialize the upload stream, and finally we can upload the file with `uploadStream.Write()`

Here is the full source code of the solution https://gitlab.com/ykcab/mongo-gridfs.